# Unable to validate login page in Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

Trying to validate a simple login page using spring, but 404 error comes.

This is the directory structure of my project.
[image: Directory Structure]

This is my LoginController.java

```
package com.example.login;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLoginForm() {
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        if (isValidUser(username, password)) {
            mav.setViewName("success");
            mav.addObject("username", username);
        } else {
            mav.setViewName("redirect:/login?error");
        }
        return mav;
    }

    private boolean isValidUser(String username, String password) {
        return username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin");
    }
}
```

This is my Login.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br>

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.login" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And last web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Dependencies in pom.xml are

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Is there a error in path or configuration or my code is wrong?

Comment: Not sure you make the correct path about jsp, according to your path ```/WEB-INF/views/``` which define in ```dispatcher-servlet.xml``` , but your jsp pages seems like be placed on the path```webapp/```?. I am doubt that how could you get into your ```login.jsp``` page  and send the request with  uri ```/login``` .

Comment: @Peng I am new to this can you tell me what should i correct??

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that your `web.xml` have oversight about spring-beans registry may be your major issue that url 404.because of the `/login` uri is in spring context not placed in `DispatcherServlet`.please refer to the code snippet below , modify `web.xml` it may helpful for you.

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-beans.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: just for try , webapp pattern is not main web design,  you   can have a look about [sprin-boot-web](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web), it will be more compact and  convenient.